# Start button doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu

I'm using Windows 8.1. I don't know why, but the start button doesn't work properly anymore. In order to open the Start screen I have to use the keyboard shortcut, which is really annoying me.

For what is worth, I've been using Windows 8.1 for a week now (it came pre-installed in the laptop I bought), and I don't think I've changed any settings.

How can I restore the original behavior?

Answer (score 28):

I’m having the same issue. I had a clean install brand new laptop just purchased about a month ago, updated to Windows 8.1 update 1 and when I try to click the start menu, nothing happens.

The only solution I know of for now is:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>, go to processes tab
2. Choose “Windows Explorer”
3. And press “Restart” on the bottom of the screen.

Alternatively, you can make a simple `.bat` file with notepad and add this code. Then you can just click on it when the problem occurs:

```
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
exit
```

Comment: windows whats going on hmm?

Comment: Oh, wow, that's great.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had this problem once, and all I did is open the task manager, right click on the Windows Explorer item, then click Restart. Also works quite well with any other Windows Explorer peculiarities and bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you have a third-party Start button solution installed.  I had Classic Shell installed previously.  One of the Windows 8 updates may have caused a conflict with Classic Shell.

I uninstalled Classic Shell and the Start button works again.

One possible clue is if you drag your taskbar to the side of the screen, and the Start button starts working again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation after a clean Systen Recovery, my solution was a simple "Restart". CTRL + ALT + DELETE -Restart.